# Concurrency violation while updating and deleting newly added rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, c#-4.0, concurrency

I've been developing a CRUD application using **Datasets** in C# and Sql Server 2012. The project is basically an agenda wich holds information about Pokémon (name, habilities, types, image, etc).
By the few months I've been facing a problem related to **concurrency violation**. In other words, when I try to delete or update rows that I've just added during the same execution of the program, the concurrency exception is generated and it isn't possible to perform any other changes in the database. So I need to restart the program in order to be able to perform the changes again (**Important Note: this exception only happens for the new rows added through C#)**.
I've been looking for a solution for this violation **(without using Entity Framework or LINQ to SQL)**, but I couldn't find anything that I could add in the C#'s source code. Does anyone knows how to handle this? What should I implement in my source code? Is there anything to do in SQL Server that could help on it?

Here is a link to my project, a backup from the database, images of the main form and the database diagram:

http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?izkat44a0e4q8em (C# source code)

http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?rj2e118pliarae2 (Sql backup)

imageshack .us /a /img 708/38 23/pokmonform .png (Main Form)

imageshack .us /a /img 18/95 46/kantopokdexdiagram .png (Database Diagram)

Comment: What is the exact error message you get? Include the whole stack trace if possible.
Also, what transaction isolation level do you use?

Comment: "System.Data.DBConcurrencyException: Concurrency violation: the DeleteCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records.
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdatedRowStatusErrors(RowUpdatedEventArgs rowUpdatedEvent, BatchCommandInfo[] batchCommands, Int32 commandCount)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdatedRowStatus(RowUpdatedEventArgs rowUpdatedEvent, BatchCommandInfo[] batchCommands, Int32 commandCount)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataRow[] dataRows, DataTableMapping tableMapping)

Comment: at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdateFromDataTable(DataTable dataTable, DataTableMapping tableMapping)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable)
   at Pokémon.MainForm.Delete_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Desktop\Pokémon 4.0\Pokémon\Pokémon\MainForm.cs:line 318

Comment: actually, I'm not using any query with isolation level... should I implement some stored procedures containing COMMIT and ROLLBACK operations?

Answer (score 0):

I have looked on your code and it seems, that you use AcceptChanges on a datatable daKanto inconsistently. In fact you use AcceptChangesDuringUpdate, which is also fine, although I prefer to call method `datatable.AcceptChanges()` explictly after the update, but your way also is fine. 
Anyway I have noticed, that you use AcceptChangesDuringUpdate in the method Delete_Click and Update__Click, but do not use it in the Save_Click, and also I think you should use AcceptChangesDuringFill in MainForm_Load, where you fill your datasets. 
I cannot guarantee you, that it will help, but I know that uniformity of data access throughout the application reduces the risk of the unexpected data consistency errors.

Comment: I've tried your tip, but it didn't work well. I've added the option 'daKanto.ContinueUpdateOnError = true;' and the concurrency exception wasn't thrown. What do you think? Would I have problems with the project or not exactly?
thank you very much!